# How can I get an javascript error's prototype member object keys?

Tags: javascript, prototype

How can I get an javascript error's prototype member object keys?

I run into this question when I catch an error, I don't know if the console output behave this way because of something special about the Error class/type/....

```js
try {
  throw new Error('sample error')
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex instanceof Error)
  //true

  console.log(ex.message)
  //sample error

  console.log(Object.keys(ex))
  //[] fine as i suppose the class/type members exist in prototype

  console.log(ex.__proto__)
  //{name:'error', message:'', constructor:.... i suppose these are the default properties of Error

  console.log(Object.keys(ex.__proto__))
  //[] how come empty array still??? 
}
```

I suppose it the last statement `console.log(Object.keys(ex.__proto__))` should return ['name', 'message'...]. Just wonder what I did wrong.

Comment: The duplicate mentions a different property, but the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ex.__proto__, "name")
# => {value: "Error", writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

The non-enumerable properties don't show up in `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the `name` and `message` properties aren't enumerable on `Error.prototype`. But you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to get a list of properties, both enumerable and not:

```js
try {
  throw new Error('sample error')
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ex.__proto__));
}
```

`Object.keys` will return an array containing only *enumerable* (and own) properties.

Note that `__proto__` is deprecated. It's preferable to use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead:

```js
try {
  throw new Error('sample error')
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(ex)));
}
```